# Cannot convert IActivity<Animal> to IActivity<Dog>

Tags: c#

In order to avoid misunderstanding, I have to rewrite my question as follows.

#### Objective:

Make generic `Executor` able to accept `IActivity<Animal>` if the executor is of type `Dog`.

#### Errors:

```
cannot convert from 'AnimalActivity' to 'IActivity<Dog>
```

#### `Trash.cs`

```
namespace Trash;

public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }

public interface IActivity<T>
{
    string Eat();
}

public class Activity<T> : IActivity<T>
{
    public virtual string Eat() => String.Empty;
}

public class DogActivity : Activity<Dog>
{
    public override string Eat()
    {
        return "Dog is eating...";
    }
}

public class AnimalActivity : Activity<Animal>
{
    public override string Eat()
    {
        return "Animal is eating...";
    }
}

public interface IExecutor<T>
{
    string Execute(IActivity<T> activity);
}

public class Executor<T> : IExecutor<T> where T : Animal
{
    public string Execute(IActivity<T> activity)
    {
        return activity.Eat();
    }
}
```

#### `Program.cs`

```
using Trash;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IExecutor<>), typeof(Executor<>));

// Others are intentionally removed for the sake of simplicity!

app.Run();
```

#### `DogsController.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Trash.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DogsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IExecutor<Dog> executor;

    public DogsController(IExecutor<Dog> executor)
    {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        //var dogActivity = new DogActivity();
        //return executor.Execute(dogActivity);

        var animalActivity = new AnimalActivity();
        return executor.Execute(animalActivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove generic type from the `Executor` type and add it to the method. `void Execute<T>(T activity) where T : Animal`

Comment: Wouldn't having "generic" executor simplify dependency injection? Register only one and reuse it for all "animals"

Comment: @RowanParkinson, You should try the suggestion from Fabio on the first comment. If you parameterize `IExecutor<T>`, and delcare  `new Executor<Dog>()`, `T` will be bound to `Dog` in `Execute(IActivity<T> activity)` and this method will not be defined for any other type.

Comment: Another option is to declare your generic type parameter as covariant (see: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "Objective", you write explicitly that an `IExecutor<Dog>` shall accept `Activity<Animal>`. In your code, you write explicitly that an `IExecutor<Dog>` shall only accept `Activity<Dog>`. Your compiler is trying to tell you that what you've written is logically inconsistent.

I am going to turn to my psychic clairvoyance powers to find out what you really wanted:

```
public string Execute(IActivity<T> activity)
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    activity.Eat(dog);
}
```

The idea is:

- If there is an activity specifically for *Dogs*, then it will be fine to run that activity with a *Dog*.
- **If there is an activity for all kinds of *Animals*, then it will be fine to run that activity with an *Animal* or a *Dog*.**

This means that you need to tell the compiler that an `IActivity<Animal>` is valid not only in places which *offer* `Animal` objects specifically, but it is also valid in places which *offer* objects of subtypes of `Animal`, like `Dog`.

This is similar to the generic `Action<T>` delegate type. The term for it is contravariance. Change the declaration of `IActivity<T>` to:

```
interface IActivity<in T>
```

Which says, any time this interface appears somewhere else (e.g. the argument of the `Execute` method), `T` really could also be a *less-derived* type (i.e. a base type of `T`).

Here is the rest (but with all the nonsense removed):

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }

interface IExecutor<T>
{
    void Execute(IActivity<T> activity);
}

class DogExecutor : IExecutor<Dog>
{
    public void Execute(IActivity<Dog> activity)
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        activity.Eat(dog);
    }
}

interface IActivity<in T>
{
    void Eat(T what);
}

class Activity<T> : IActivity<T> { public void Eat(T what) { } }
```

```
IExecutor<Dog> executor = new DogExecutor();
IActivity<Dog> dogActivity = new Activity<Dog>();
executor.Execute(dogActivity);
IActivity<Animal> animalActivity = new Activity<Animal>();
executor.Execute(animalActivity);
```

In case my psychic powers have failed me, this is embarassing and you should ignore this answer.

---

#### Why you cannot return an `IEnumerable<T>` and how you might be able to work around it

Marking a generic type parameter as contravariant has implications. The compiler will make sure that you abide by certain restrictions.

Consider this:

```
class DogExecutor
{
    void Execute(IActivity<Dog> activity)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Dog clone = activity.Clone(dog);
        clone.Bark();
    }
}

interface IActivity<T>
{
    T Clone(T original);
}
```

Here, the `DogActivity` *requires* that the type returned by `IActivity<Dog>.Clone` is `Dog`, or a *more-derived* type, like `Poodle`.

This is because `DogActivity.Execute` assumes that when cloning a `Dog`, it will also be able to perform *Dog-only* operations (like `Bark`) on the clone.

*However*, consider the case where the *real* `activity` object that is passed to `Execute` is the following type:

```
class GeneticallyUnstableAnimalActivity : IActivity<Animal>
{
    Animal Clone(Animal original)
    {
        DNA dna = original.GetDNA();
        DNA new_dna = dna.MutateRandomly();
        Animal new_animal = CreateAnimalFromDNA(new_dna);
        // "new_animal" could be anything. It is not necessarily
        // the same kind of animal as "original".
        return new_animal;
    }
}
```

Were it not for the contravariance constraint, this would be a perfectly reasonable implementation for a `Clone` method.

However, this means that `clone` in `DogExecutor` is *not guaranteed* to be a `Dog`. It could be anything. It could be a `Cat`, and then `DogExecutor.Execute` would attempt to call `Bark` on a `Cat`. Blasphemy! Because of this, the compiler will forbid it.

The same is true if the return type is something like `IEnumerable<T>`.

When solving this, you have to make a decision.

(1)

Perhaps you acknowledge that a `GeneticallyUnstableAnimalActivity` would be valid in your program. In this case, *you must accept that you cannot stop an implementation of `IActivity.Clone` from returning something that you didn't want at runtime*. You must check the object that was returned at runtime. For example, consider this:

```
interface IActivity<in T>
{
    object Clone(T original);
}
```

```
void Execute(IActivity<Dog> activity)
{
    object clone = activity.Clone(...);
    // Rather than throwing an exception, you might also find a way
    // to deal with genetically mutated non-Dog clones here.
    if (!(clone is Dog cloneDog)) throw new GeneticMutationException();
    ...
}
```

If you want to restrict the returned type to at least `Animal` instead of `object`, you would need to introduce a specialized `IAnimalActivity` interface for it, but that will make the `DogExecutor` more complicated since it would require that the activity being used is not just any `IActivity`, but `IAnimalActivity`.

(2A)

You assert that `Clone` really must return exactly the same type back.

The most *direct* way of specifying this is modifying the `Clone` method in the `IActivity<T>` interface:

```
TOriginal Clone<TOriginal>(TOriginal original)
    where TOriginal : T;
```

At this point, the rules you have put down for yourself are starting to get a little complicated. The compiler will constantly be nagging you to make sure that you abide by your own rules.

To clarify what I mean by that, imagine implementing this method in `class AnimalActivity : IActivity<Animal>`. What would it look like?

```
TOriginal Clone<TOriginal>(TOriginal original)
    where TOriginal : Animal
{
    // What to write here?
}
```

(2B)

You can also achieve this by splitting `IActivity<T>` into two, logically separated interfaces. This might even make more sense overall. The second interface would only be used for cloning (or "spawning" in your case):

```
interface ICloner<T>
{
    T Clone(T original);
}
```

Note that the generic type parameter `T` is not variant (neither covariant nor contravariant). Of course, this would also have implications on how your `Executor` infrastructure is designed. To be precise, the methods in the `Executor` which need cloning will take an `ICloner<T>`, and then the compiler will insist that you really pass a `DogCloner` to a `DogExecutor`, and not just *any* `AnimalCloner`.

---

If you go for (2), then be warned that

- you *will* realise sooner or later that your rules are too complicated for your own good
- you *will* realise sooner or later that there must be exceptions to your rules
- the compiler *will not* let you break your own rules. *You have already experienced this when you tried to add a method that returns `IEnumerable<T>`*.

Further reading on the general topic of abusing the type system to encode your world rules:

[Of Wizards And Warriors, by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

(It is a really *long*, but also really good article).

Comment: @RowanParkinson A generic type parameter can be either covariant or contravariant. It can never be both. I will update the answer to explain why, and how you might be able to work around it.

Comment: @RowanParkinson I've added additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead

```cs
class Executor<T> where T : Animal
{
    public void Execute(Activity<T> activity)
    {
        activity.Eat();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the short reply I'm on my phone

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because

1. `Executor<Derived>` needs `IActivity<Derived>` and
2. `AnimalActivity` gives it `IActivity<Base>`.

To be honest it is not clear what you're trying to achieve but you can make your code work by making Executor non-generic and accept `IActivity<Base>` (in your case `IActivity<Animal>`) *(Which makes sense because the executor should not be a different class depending on what kind of activity it works with)*:

```
interface IExecutor
{
    void Execute(IActivity<Animal> activity);
}

class Executor : IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(IActivity<Animal> activity)
    {
        activity.Eat();
    }
}
```

Then

```
var executor = new Executor();
var animalActivity = new AnimalActivity();
executor.Execute(animalActivity);
```

will print

```
Animal is eating...
```

---

More generally, your code mixes

- generics,
- interfaces and
- inheritance

but for the example as shown one of these methods is enough.

For example here's a version with just interfaces, no generics and no inheritance (I don't know why 'XActivity' classes exist (rather than `Eat` being a method on the `Animal`) the `Animal` nad `Dog` classes are disconnected from the rest and not necessary):

```
class Animal { }
class Dog  { } // No inheritance even here

interface IActivity { void Eat(); }


class DogActivity : IActivity
{
    public void Eat() => Console.WriteLine("Dog is eating...");
}

class AnimalActivity : IActivity
{
    public void Eat() => Console.WriteLine("Animal is eating...");
}


interface IExecutor
{
    void Execute(IActivity activity);
}

class Executor : IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(IActivity activity) => activity.Eat();
}
```

Here's a version with just inheritance (I left the interface on IExecutor but this is not relevant here).

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }


class AnimalActivity
{
    public virtual void Eat() => Console.WriteLine("Animal is eating...");
}

class DogActivity: AnimalActivity
{
    public override void Eat() => Console.WriteLine("Dog is eating...");
}


interface IExecutor
{
    void Execute(AnimalActivity activity);
}

class Executor : IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(AnimalActivity activity) => activity.Eat();
}
```